# Passing data/message from flutter apps to other apps

Tags: dart, flutter

i am trying to pass data from my flutter app to other apps. The purpose is to send the download link for my app to another app(say watsapp,facebook,twitter etc.).
I am using flutter plugin share 0.6.0+1. i added the package as instructed. But when i ran the program, the following error was displayed:

`[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method share on channel plugins.flutter.io/share)
E/flutter ( 8153): #0      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:300:7)
E/flutter ( 8153): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8153): #1      Share.share (package:share/share.dart:44:20)
E/flutter ( 8153): #2      _MyHomePageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:unit_converter/main.dart:409:34)
E/flutter ( 8153): #3      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:513:14)
E/flutter ( 8153): #4      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:568:30)
E/flutter ( 8153): #5      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:120:24)
E/flutter ( 8153): #6      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:242:9)
E/flutter ( 8153): #7      TapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:204:7)
E/flutter ( 8153): #8      GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:156:27)
E/flutter ( 8153): #9      _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:218:20)
E/flutter ( 8153): #10     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:192:22)
E/flutter ( 8153): #11     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:149:7)
E/flutter ( 8153): #12     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:101:7)
E/flutter ( 8153): #13     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:85:7)
E/flutter ( 8153): #14     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1136:13)
E/flutter ( 8153): #15     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
E/flutter ( 8153): #16     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:931:7)
E/flutter ( 8153): #17     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:223:10)
E/flutter ( 8153): #18     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:144:5)`

The following is the content of my pubspec.yaml file:

```
    dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  dart2_constant: ^1.0.2+dart2
  math_expressions: ^1.0.0
  shared_preferences: ^0.4.3
  #loader_search_bar: ^1.0.3+1
  material_search: ^0.2.8
  path_provider: '>=0.3.0'
  sqflite: any
  flutter_colorpicker: ^0.2.1
  intl: ^0.15.7
  auto_size_text: ^0.3.0
  cloud_firestore: ^0.9.0
  animated_text_kit: ^1.3.0
  share: ^0.6.0+1
```

The following is my implementation:

```
Share.share('Hi, take a time to click and download this app: market://search?q=pname:com.myappbase.appname');
```

Please can anyone point me to what i am doing wrong. i seem to have tried ieverything but these same errors have been coming up.Or is there a more elegant way this can be done? Thanks

Comment: Have you terminated app and re Run it from scratch?? It happens mostly when you added dependency and just hot reload/restart the app instead of full restart of app.

Comment: Wow. Thanks a bunch @Harsha pulikollu. i terminated and reran the program, this solved it for me, Thanks once again.

Comment: posted as answer, feel free to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must **terminate** the app and **rerun** it from scratch as `share` dependency required `platform channel` methods to be called. the app has to terminate and rerun from scratch.